# Abrir txt via pyscript com pandas

Tags: pandas

O que pode estar de errado neste código? Estou tentando abrir um txt no navegador usando as regras do pyscript

Quando não fica todo branco, fica com este erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<py-env>
    - pandas
</py-env>

<body>
    <py-script>
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/Teste.txt', delimiter = "\t")
        print(df)
    </py-script>        
</body>
```

Comment: O que está dando de errado?

Comment: Quando não fica todo branco, fica com este erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem algumas alterações que precisam ser efetuadas:

1. Utilize a tag `py-env` dentro da tag `head`
2. Adicione o caminho do arquivo dentro de `paths` na tag `py-env` e use esse arquivo apenas pelo nome no código.
3. Adicione uma div com id para exibir o resultado da tag `py-script`
4. Adicione o atributo `output` na tag `py-script` com o id da div que irá exibir o resultado

Exemplo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  <py-env>
    - pandas
    - paths:
      - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Quijaua/d5f9fd7aba63d1701aafb2765776c008/raw/050c3efab8dea9ee9d94f2fd3a29ba2df33d3b62/uf.txt
  </py-env>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="teste"></div>
  <py-script output="teste">
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("uf.txt", delimiter = "\t")
    print(df)
  </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```